# Lexical or Preprocessor issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, precompile

[image: Error descriptions]

I'm getting these 2 errors whilst archiving the project.

- Macro name is missing
- Macro names must be identifiers

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: http://take.ms/rbm Problem solved... Here was the strange bug with debug definition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it says on the tin.

The first is `#define`, if you have this on its own, what is it defining? You need an identifier/name after the `#define`, such as `#define VARIABLE`.

The second does provide some sort of name, but it's simply a number. Identifiers cannot start with a number (just like variable names can't). and hence isn't classed as an identifier.

Comment: http://take.ms/qam i checked twice all the defines in the project. But all is correct...

Comment: Very interesting. The fact the error is coming from <built-in> is confusing. What are the contents of your .pch (the file it failed on)? It may be worth doing a clean build, and closing/reopening Xcode, just to make sure it isn't a 'glitch'

Comment: nothing special. http://take.ms/1am already clean project and restart several times Xcode and mac. This error appears while archiving the project. And here's mine preprocess settings http://take.ms/7am

Comment: For starters, those preprocess macros are bunk. `DEBUG=0` will still mean `DEBUG` is still defined, which is typically how they're used (`#ifdef DEBUG ...`). Instead, they should either include `DEBUG` or nothing. So for Debug build, use `DEBUG`, and release, use nothing. For example, see http://i.imgur.com/OeXtk.png

Comment: http://monosnap.com/image/SLUF4F8wr78qWmLY481u9BZHk by removing this property all is gone and project get ready to release)

Comment: (or use NDEBUG for Release, which explicitly states 'No Debugging')

Answer (score 2):

I got the same errors when attempting to define preprocessor macros in Build Settings as follows

```
Preprocessor Macros
    DEBUG=1 MY_MACRO = 1
```

So, the parser does not like spaces, i.e. MY_MACRO=1

Comment: This is useful information! Also remember to check the debug and release macros...My issue was only in the release config so it was hard to track down!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `macro` without giving `name`. You've to use `#define` with name as follows and have to give value for that `macro` 

`#define  macroname  macrovalue` 
 
second one is  you can't use `numbers` in `macro` but you are giving 
`#define 0 1` 
it should be like 
`#define ZERO 1`

Comment: You do **not** have to give a macrovalue. You can easily have a `#define NAME` without a value, and use it in the form `#ifdef NAME`

Answer (score 0):

you are using 0 as a NAME of a macro, a digit is no valid name for any variable, functions or macro. all identifiers must start with a letter(or _) :)

Comment: nope... my defines are correct. All starts from letter or "_" http://monosnap.com/image/Pm4cdf2qsV3CZH1rLPLU88r0L